# Assembly instructions showing how zenbleed was found

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-architecture, amd-processor

While looking at this [zenbleed](https://lock.cmpxchg8b.com/zenbleed.html) article, it was found that a randomly generated sequence of instructions and the same sequence but with randomized alignment, serialization and speculation fences added produced final states that didn't match.

For example

```
Original Code              Fuzzed Code
--------------------       --------------------
movnti [rbp+0x0],ebx       movnti [rbp+0x0],ebx
                           sfence
rcr dh,1                   rcr dh,1
                           lfence
sub r10, rax               sub r10, rax
                           mfence
rol rbx, cl                rol rbx, cl
                           nop
xor edi,[rbp-0x57]         xor edi,[rbp-0x57]
```

It was mentioned in that article that it **could** indicate a bug

> If the final states don’t match, then there must have been some error
> in how they were executed micro-architecturally - that could indicate
> a bug.

**Notes**

> As developers we monitor the macro-architectural state, that’s just
> things like register values. There is also the micro-architectural
> state which is mostly invisible to us, like the branch predictor,
> out-of-order execution state and the instruction pipeline.

**Question**

Are there any situations when it's not a bug when executed micro-architecturally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when executed micro-architecturally

This phrasing doesn't make sense.  Every instruction sequence has to get executed by the microarchitecture (CPU hardware design).  The CPU hardware doesn't have any other way to run machine code.

Any observable (architectural, not timing) results always need to match what would happen if they executed one at a time, in program order (except for memory contents observed from other threads).  i.e. out-of-order exec has to preserve the illusion of a serial execution model.

Since `lfence`, `mfence`, `nop`, etc. have no effect on the architectural state (register / memory contents), they shouldn't change anything **for single-threaded code**.  **If they do create a difference, that's always a problem.**  I think that's what you meant to ask, and it's what the quotes are saying.

---

There are instructions like `rdtsc` and `rdpmc` that read a timestamp or performance counter; those will of course give different results when you put slow instructions (TSC) or extra instructions/uops into a sequence.  `rdpmc` is essentially reading microarchitectural counters into architectural state (register values), and `rdtsc` is reading time, so there was never any expectation that they'd give the same results with or without serialization.